# Detect variable change without observer/listener?

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there a way to detect a variable change without an traditional observer/listener pattern ?

Im using an ECS ( Entity Component System ) [Artemis ODB](https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb) which does not support callbacks for value changes in components, so i need to implement them on my own.

The only way i could imagine is to use some sort of history of the values. Or are there other techniques ?

Comment: How is this related to algorithm? Seems more like a design problem. But one ways is to use some sort of Event Dispatch mechanism when there is a change in component. And listen to those events elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @SomeDude Thanks... i also thought about this, but i actually want to find some "generic" way :/ Thats why im searching for a way without observers/listeners

Comment: I don't understand why the observer pattern is not an option here. Could you provide an example that illustrates the problem?